# windows forms connect to local database

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have created a very basic windows form application using visual studio 2015. 
A service based database has been added (mdf database), and a table has been created.. 
The database has been added to the service explore,  and i can see the connection string in the setting file.

I am simple trying to open a connection to the database to be able to write to it..  Cant seem to find any basic example..
Tried to use this :-

```
  using (var con = new 
SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.MyConnectionString))
                {
                    con.Open();

                }

            }
```

but no luck.  Seem to get the following error

```
A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share."}
```

my connection string :-

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirector‌​y|\Data\mydb.mdf;Int‌​egrated Security=True
```

Comment: Can you show the exact details of that _MyConnectionString_?

Comment: @Steve . Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Data\mydb.mdf;Integrated Security=True

Comment: When you use the DataDirectory substitution string in a WinForms application then it will be replaced by the path to the directory where your program starts. Inside a Visual Studio debug session this path is the project folder and then BIN\DEBUG or BIN\X86\DEBUG. Check if your database MDF file is located there. (Consider also the Data subfolder IE: projectfolder\BIN\DEBUG\DATA\myDb.mdf)

Comment: @steve hi, yes they database is also located there.. it not part of the solution though?